# pygame custom font putting letters in the wrong place

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

My IDE i'm using (pyscripter) has bugs with fonts and such so i'm trying to use my own font. 
I'm having problems getting the letters to appear where i want them to. for example,

```
draw_word('abab',[15,10])
```

makes the word 'abab' (i have only made a and b thus far) as intended. however, if i were to do:

```
draw_word('abab',[50,10])
```

then the letters are streched out. I wanted the word to be put on the screen at x=50.

```
draw_word('abab',[5,10])
```

this scrunches the word up, instead of putting it to the screen at x=5.

how do i solve this problem and what is causing it?

the full code is:

```
draw_word('abab',[15,10])
```

this calls:

```
  def draw_word(word,xy):
    loc=1 # short for location
    for letter in word:
        draw_letter(letter,[(xy[0]*loc),xy[1]]) #uses loc to move the letter over
        loc+=1 #next letter
```

this calls:

```
def draw_letter(letter,xy):
l=pygame.image.load(('letters/'+letter+'.png')).convert()
l.set_colorkey(WHITE)
screen.blit(l,xy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `print xy[0]*loc` in `for letter in word` and you see why you have letters in wrong places.

Example for `x=50`: first letter 50*1=50, next letter 50*2=100, next letter 50*3=150

You need:

```
def draw_word(word,xy):
    loc=0 # short for location
    for letter in word:
        draw_letter(letter,[(xy[0]+loc),xy[1]]) #uses loc to move the letter over
        loc += 20 #next letter
```

Use other value in `loc += 20` to get better distance between letters.

---

BTW: you can write it this way:

```
def draw_word(word,xy, distance=20)
    for letter in word:
        draw_letter(letter,xy)
        xy[0] += distance
```

and now you can use it

```
draw_word('abab',[15,10]) # distance will be 20
draw_word('abab',[15,10], 30) # distance will be 30
```

Comment: i have changed it to xy[0]+(15*loc)), which works but now i can never put the word anywhere less than x=15. how do i fix this?

Comment: See new version with `distance`

Comment: See `loc=0` in first version.